# Remove element from Tree Data Structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

I have a Tree Structure like this:

```
    10
   /  \
  5    12
 / \   / \
3   7 11  18
```

Values bigger than the element before get linked right, smaller ones left.
Now I want to add a "Remove" function, but I somehow don't get it right. 
For example, when I remove the 5, it should look like this:

```
    10
   /  \
  3    12
   \   / \
    7 11  18
```

The smaller linked element (3) from the removed element (5) should be linked with the element the removed element was linked with.
Here is my remove function:

```
public TElement RootElement;

    public void Remove(int value)
    {
        if (RootElement == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't delete nothing!");
        }

        if (RootElement._left == null && RootElement._right == null)
        {
            RootElement = null;
            return;
        }

        RootElement = RootElement.RemoveElement(value, RootElement);
    }

public TElement RemoveElement(int value, TElement current)
        {


            if (value != _value)
            {
                if (value < _value)
                {
                    _left.RemoveElement(value, current);
                }

                if (value > _value)
                {
                    _right.RemoveElement(value, current);
                }
            }

            if (value == _value)
            {
                if (_value < current._value)
                {
                    if (_left == null && _right == null)
                    {

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        current._left = _left;
                        _left._right = _right;
                    }
                }

                if (_value > current._value)
                {
                    if (_left == null && _right == null)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        current._right = _right;
                        _right._left = _left;
                    }
                }               
            }

            current = this;
            return current;
        }
```

`_left` is a pointer to the smaller element, and `_right` points to a bigger element.
If you need more code, just ask.

Comment: This operation requires updating the parent of some element, but in this code I cannot see it. Moreover why `Remove` function is not void. why it returns a value?

Comment: Thats `current` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

```
 public TElement RemoveElement(int value, TElement current)
        {


            if (value != _value)
            {
                if (value < _value)
                {
                    current = this;
                    _left.RemoveElement(value, current);
                }

                if (value > _value)
                {
                    current = this;
                    _right.RemoveElement(value, current);
                }
            }

            if (value == _value)
            {
                if (_value < current._value)
                {
                    if (_left == null && _right == null)
                    {
                        current._left = null; 
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        current._left = _left;
                        _left._right = _right;
                    }
                }

                if (_value > current._value)
                {
                    if (_left == null && _right == null)
                    {
                        current._right = null;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        current._right = _right;
                        _right._left = _left;
                    }
                }               
            }


            return current;
        }
```